# USB detected but not found in /dev

Tags: usb, arch-linux, block-device

I have a [Parabola Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola_GNU/Linux-libre) (based on Arch Linux) installation with Kernel 4.9.6.

When I insert a USB external hard disk I can see it in `lsusb` as

> Bus 002 Device 055: ID 0411:01de BUFFALO INC. (formerly MelCo., Inc.) External Hard Drive HD-PCTU3 [Buffalo MiniStation]

However, I cannot find it as a block device anywhere in `/dev`. For instance, `lsblk` returns

```
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                 8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
└─sda1              8:1    0 223.6G  0 part 
  └─root          254:0    0 223.6G  0 crypt
    ├─matrix-swap 254:1    0     2G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─matrix-root 254:2    0 199.4G  0 lvm   /
    ├─matrix-boot 254:3    0     2G  0 lvm   /boot
    └─matrix-var  254:4    0  20.2G  0 lvm   /var
```

Here `sda` is my hard disk with some LVM partitions. The USB device doesn't show up in `/dev/disk/by-id` either. A check with `dmesg` yields

```
usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 55 using ehci-pci
```

and nothing else.

I can't figure out what is the problem. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 34):

The most common cause:

You have upgraded the kernel recently, but haven't yet rebooted into it. When you connect a new device, udev tries to load modules matching the *running* kernel – but you don't have them anymore! Instead your `/lib/modules` only has files for the *installed* newer kernel.

Check whether `uname -r` and `pacman -Q linux` show different versions; if so, reboot.

Comment: What if they show the same version?

Comment: Has anyone tried to solve this already? It's rather annoying.